# Soundcloud widget needs to be pressed twice in order to play music since last week

Tags: mobile-safari, soundcloud

I am using widgets from soundcloud to play music from a webview. Since last week users has to press play, pause, play in order to hear anything (instead of on the first tap). The same thing seems to happen in Safari mobile and can be tested here:

https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html

Does anyone know a valid work-around for this? Maybe using javascript somehow? It does not help to simply call widget.play() widget.stop() on startup.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chromium 34.0. Works properly. Are You familiar, with upcoming change to [SoundCloud API 2](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/introducing-javascript-sdk-version-2)?

Comment: hey, thanks for reporting, does this only happen on mobile browsers?

Comment: Correct, it works fine in other browsers, but not in safari mobile and not android browser.

I will review soundcloud api 2, and see if it would solve my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soundcloud has fixed this issue on their side.